# How to secure zappa `remote_env` bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, bucket, zappa

I am successfully deploy my `Django` and using `remote_env` in the zappa yml file. One concern here is security

I split into 2 buckets

1. `env.json`
2. `Django`
   The concern right now is `env.json` in the `remote_env` is not public and `Django` on behalf of AWS Lambda is unable to read it. Then my zappa raises `500`

I had posted my question in the [zappa github](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1935), but people there their rarely answer the question then I decided to put my question to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zappa does the job already. I don't need to do anything!

[image: env.json with AccessDenied]